# Is this exercise about field of quotients correctly stated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm doing Exercise 6 in textbook *Algebra* by Saunders MacLane and Garrett Birkhoff.

> Show that any monomorphism $D \rightarrow D^{\prime}$ of **domains** yields a corresponding monomorphism $\operatorname{Quot}(D) \rightarrow \operatorname{Quot}\left(D^{\prime}\right)$ of fields.

In this textbook and on this wikipedia [page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Field_of_fractions#/Construction), the field of quotients is constructed from integral domain, not just domain. As such, I suspect that the authors mean integral domain rather than domain.

Could you please verify if my understanding is fine?

Comment: Can you provide the authors definition of “domain”?

Comment: @Knaus A domain is a nontrivial ring without zero divisors. An integral domain is a commutative domain.

Comment: I imagine there is a mistake then. There are constructions generalizing field of fractions, but it obviously won’t be a field in the non commutative case, (you want there to be an inclusion of a non commutative ring) so it should rather be called the skew field of fractions.

Comment: @Knaus Your comment solved my problem. May you post it as an answer?

Comment: Either that, or their definition of Quot works for any ring, and in this case effectively first quotients out the commutator ideal, and then take the field of fractions of the resulting integral domain.

Comment: I have checked the book, the authors never defined just "domain" in the way you did. They use the word "domain" with the same meaning as "integral domain".

Comment: Thank you for your reference @QiZhu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If their definition of Quot is such that for a domain (not necessarily commutative) $R$ there is a monomorphism $R\rightarrow \mathrm{Quot}(R)$, then clearly Quot$(R)$ is not necessarily a field, as it is non-commutative whenever $R$ is.

Comment: For future readers, let me note that this particular textbook uses the notions "domain" and "integral domain" synonymously.